# redirect to another function in a controller in magento

Tags: magento, controller

I have magento site.

I have a controller ,how can i redirect into another function in this controller?

That means ,there have two functions:

```
1.test()


i want to redirect from test1() to test2()
```

how can i do this?

```
How can i redirect from one function to another function in the same controller?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put something like this in **test1** action.

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/test2', array(if you want to pass something then from here you can pass ));
```

Answer (score 8):

There are three redirecting functions available in frontend controller which are:

```
_redirect()
_redirectUrl()
_redirectReferer()
```

`_redirect('frontName/controllerName/actionName/param1/param2')` is used for internal redirection.
`_redirectUrl($fullUrl)` is used for external redirection.
`_redirectReferer()` is used to redirect to the referer url.

Hope this gives more info.